# Using R data.table for selecting from a column containg vector elements

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to learn the recommended ways to create a new column for a data table when the column of interest is a list (or vector), and the selection is done relative to another column, and there may be a preliminary selection done as part of a chain.

Consider these data named (tmp). We want to find the minimum value of sacStartT greater than stimTime (in the real data one or the other of these could be empty and no minimum exist).

```
tmp = data.table("pid" = c(14,14,9,9),"trialNumber" = c(25,26,25,26),"stimTime" = c(100,200,1,2),"sacStartT" = list(c(98,99,101,102), c(201,202), c(5), c(-2,-3,3)))
```

This works:

```
tmp[,"mintime" := as.integer(min(unlist(sacStartT)[unlist(sacStartT)>stimTime])),by=seq_len(nrow(tmp))]
```

But if I wanted to first subselect the data I don't know how to get that row number for the row-by-row analysis, e.g.

```
tmp[pid == 9][,"mintime" := as.integer(min(unlist(sacStartT)[unlist(sacStartT)>stimTime])),by=seq_len(nrow(.N))]
```

fails because `.N` refers to the number of rows in tmp, and not the subset in the chain.

In summary, the question is the composition of:

1. Recommendations for doing this row by row analysis?
2. How to find the right number for the by argument in a chain?
3. Recommendations for dealing with data.table elements that contain lists? Do you just have to manually unlist them all?

Comment: Just a note, your `stimTime` is a digit longer than `sacStartT`, so the logical  right now returns all `FALSE`. I was trying to figure out why your first code didn't work.

Comment: Thanks. That was me trying to cut and paste a mwe. I replaced with a line of code to generate the example to be easier to test, and to actually demonstrate my problem.

Comment: r you looking for `tmp[pid == 9, mintime := as.integer(min(unlist(sacStartT)[unlist(sacStartT)>stimTime])), by=seq_len(tmp[pid==9, .N])]`? there should be an issue for this in the github regarding the use of `.N` in `by=`

Comment: Not quite. The goal is to be able to chain many data.table [] operations together and to be able to easily refer to the number of row in the "subset" version of the table that is being passed along.